# Realizar vários GET com XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

como eu faço para que o XMLHttpRequest envie vários pedidos usando uma lista com js puro, exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte lista de nomes

```
Fernando
Lucas
```

Quero pegar essa lista e realizar um post com um nome por vez e exibir a resposta da solicitação, até acabar todos os itens.

Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: E cada nome deve ser um ajax separado certo? Onde queres mostar esses resultados? queres mostrar à medida que vão chegando ou todos juntos.

Comment: Cada nome vai ser uma request separada, quero mostrar em um simples alert por enquanto e ir mostrando a medida que vão chegando, muito obrigado pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Mas pedidos `get` ou `post` ? No titulo está uma coisa mas depois no meio da pergunta está outra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o que pretende o ideal será criar um array de nomes e à medida que o percorre faz requisições ajax criando e configurando os objetos `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const url = "http://www.a_sua_pagina_aqui.php";
const nomes = ["Fernando","Lucas"];

nomes.forEach((nome) => { //percorrer todos os nomes
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //criar o objeto para o pedido

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //apenas dentro do if tem a resposta à requisição
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         console.log(xhttp.responseText); //resposta vem no responseText
      }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", url , true); //requisição do tipo POST com true para ser assíncrono
  xhttp.send("nome=" + nome); //parâmetros enviados aqui, neste caso apenas o nome
});
```

É importante relembrar que a ordem com que recebe as respostas não será necessariamente a ordem com que as enviou!

Answer (score 3):

Simples!

```
var i = 0;
var user = [
        "Pedro",
        "Jose",
        "Marcos",
        "Lucas"
        ];


 function ajax( get ) {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

 // readyState
 if (this.readyState == 4) {

    if(this.status == 200) {

        // alert('XHTTP LOAD');
        reload(i);
        i++;

    } else {

        alert('ERRO XHTTP');

    }
}
};
 xhttp.open("GET", "nomes.php?user=" + encodeURI( get ) , true); // start
 xhttp.send();
}

function reload(i) {
   if(i >= user.length ) alert('FIM'); else ajax( user[ i ]);
}
reload(i); // start
```